# How to set system properties in substrate blockchain for private network?

Tags: blockchain, substrate, polkadot

I am deploying my own private blockchain using the substrate code. In which how to set the token decimals and token symbol while deploying it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These parameters are set in the node's `chain_spec.rs` in the [template code](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/master/node/src/chain_spec.rs) and an example from [polkadot code](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/node/service/src/chain_spec.rs) that ingests a JSON file for a specific chain ([examples](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/tree/master/node/service/res))

To get this generated for you automatically that you can then customize, build the node and then follow the flow [outlined in the cumulus workshop](https://substrate.dev/cumulus-workshop/#/en/1-prep/2-chain-spec) to get a plain chainspec, edit as you see fit, and then generate a custom final one that you can use when starting your nodes.